# Bad State:Can't call test() once tests have begun running

Tags: flutter, testing, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am facing an issue during running the flutter bloc test. Initial test case is running successful but the bloc test is giving this exception.
Here is my test code:

```dart
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import'package:dictionary_bloc/features/dictionary_search/data/data_source/dictionary_fnx.dart';
import'package:dictionary_bloc/features/dictionary_search/presentation/bloc/dictionary_cubit.dart';
import'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main(){
  group("cubit testing", () {

    late DictionaryCubit dictionaryCubit;

    setUp((){
      dictionaryCubit = DictionaryCubit(DictionaryFnx());
    });

    test("Initial test", () {
      expect(dictionaryCubit.state, NoWordSearchedState());
    });


    group("word search group", () {
      test("number searching", (){
        blocTest<DictionaryCubit,DictionaryState>("word search not successful",
            build: ()=> dictionaryCubit,
            act: (cubit) async => await cubit.getWordSearched("1"),
            expect: ()=> <DictionaryState>[ErrorState("No WordFound")]
        );
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `blocTest` from inside the `test()`, `blocTest` is already a test